# Mass Effect 3 public match locked

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

So I was playing Mass Effect 3 online yesterday’s and everything was fine. 
 I tried playing again today and there is a lock on the side of the Team settings in the quick match menu. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image: lock next to team]
[image: lock next to team]

Comment: I most certainly hope that they didn't kill it. The [N7HQ ](http://n7hq.masseffect.com/) site is still online though